# Android Card.io library issue

Tags: android, credit-card

Im trying to implement [card.io](https://www.card.io/) feature for my Android application. I have tried [sample application given here](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK). I have tried with many cards but of no use. I wonder if its the issue with SDK. Is there any alternative way to do the same.

Comment: What problem you are getting ?

Comment: This library scans only embossed cards [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/U0nZw.png) . It doesnt scan normal debit cards.

Comment: @Adiga : normal cards like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, card.io currently cannot scan non-embossed cards. This is a limitation that the developer aware of, check [this](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/issues/20) issue raised in card.io github page.and go through [this](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/issues/56) link also.

hope it answers your question